# Error Found on std::stoi comparison byte 0x90

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I was coding using on C++ with the compiled MSVC and noticed something:

When I Write some stuff like:

```cpp
if ( std::stoi ( "4D", nullptr, 16 ) == '\x4D' )
                Beep ( 200, 400 );
```

I can hear the Beep, but when I write something like:

```
if ( std::stoi ( "90", nullptr, 16 ) == '\x90' )
            Beep ( 200, 400 );
```

The comparison doesn't activate the Beep.

I Searched in many places but didn't find any way to resolve this.

Comment: `char` is signed. `'\x90'` converts to some negative integer, not to `0x90`. Why do you feel the need to use `char` literals on the right hand side?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `char` MAY be signed, or it MAY be unsigned. It is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 0):

`stoi()` returns an `int`, not a `char`. Use `0x4D` instead of `'\x4D'`, and `0x90` instead of `'\x90'`:

```
if ( std::stoi ( "4D", nullptr, 16 ) == 0x4D )
    Beep ( 200, 400 );
```

```
if ( std::stoi ( "90", nullptr, 16 ) == 0x90 )
    Beep ( 200, 400 );
```